# Please teach me how to laravel-querybuilder left join

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

```
select t2.id,name,count(*) as toroku ,
sum(case when tion_flg <> 0 THEN 1     ELSE 0 END ) as riyou,t2.upload_at
FROM id_master as t1
LEFT JOIN id_upload as t2
ON t1.upload_id = t2.upload_id
GROUP BY t2.id,t2.name,t2.upload_at
ORDER BY id
```

I' d like to make laravel query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DB::table('id_master AS t1')
    ->select(DB::raw('
        t2.id,
        name,
        count(*) AS toroku,
        SUM(CASE WHEN tion_flg <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS riyou,
        t2.upload_at'))
    ->leftJoin('id_upload AS t2', 't1.upload_id', '=', 't2.upload_id')
    ->groupBy('t2.id','t2.name','t2.upload_at')
    ->orderBy('id')
->get();
```

Comment: Have error.  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()      i'd like to know reason

Comment: [The method exists](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#retrieving-results). I replaced `->get()` with `->toSql()` in my setup and the query is correct. If your class is namespaced try with `\DB::table` (note the backslash at the begining)